# Install mqtt client libraries on raspberry pi

Tags: c

I've been trying to compile the Paho MQTT client libraries on raspbian buster. Cloned the github source:

`git clone https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c.git`

As per the README file I've run make (OK except for 1 warning that 'rc1 not used') then sudo make install which happily copies sundry MQTTxx.h and MQTTxx.c files into the /usr/include directory.

However, attempts to compile a Paho demo program results in:

```
richard@grigio:[~]: gcc mqtest.c
/tmp/ccvjYcVw.o: In function `main':
mqtest.c:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `MQTTClient_create'
mqtest.c:(.text+0x8c): undefined reference to `MQTTClient_connect'
mqtest.c:(.text+0xe4): undefined reference to `MQTTClient_publishMessage'
mqtest.c:(.text+0x114): undefined reference to `MQTTClient_waitForCompletion'
mqtest.c:(.text+0x138): undefined reference to `MQTTClient_disconnect'
mqtest.c:(.text+0x144): undefined reference to `MQTTClient_destroy'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

so I thought I needed to link the library:

```
richard@grigio:[~]: gcc mqtest.c -lMQTTClient
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lMQTTClient
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

MQTTClient.h and MQTTClient.c are present in /usr/include so what am I doing wrong, please?

Comment: Looking at the [Makefile](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c/blob/master/Makefile), you might need to add `-lpaho-mqtt3c` instead. If in doubt, re-run `sudo make install` and take note of any `lib*.so` flying by.

Comment: Thanks, @Botje - that did the trick! I suppose I should spend time and work out why, but my 70odd year old brain complains that it's full-up!